# pped 47 frames! the application may be doing too much work on its main thread. on device android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am getting this message in logcat, while running app on device, I have used fragments from activity I am jumping to this activity,below is my code for this particular activity.
I don't understand why I am getting this message as I have run everything on background. I am also using DrawerLayout for navigation and that uses fragments and my previous activity also do the same, is this could be the reason for skipped frames ?

```
 private class GetProjectInfo extends AsyncTask<String,String, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();

            jObj.put("project_id",prefs.getString("project_id",""));

            HttpClient httpClient  = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Constants.TATA_PROJECTS_URL);

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jObj.toString());

            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            se.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");

            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

            Constants.project_data = result;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

         if(s == null || s.equals(""))
        {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject(s);

                JSONObject dataObj = resObj.getJSONObject("abc");

                String project_id = dataObj.getString("project_id");

                String project_name = dataObj.getString("project_name");

                String project_location = dataObj.getString("project_location");

                String project_img = dataObj.getString("project_img_url");

                String project_background = dataObj.getString("project_background");

                String project_tagline = dataObj.getString("project_tagline");

                String project_text = dataObj.getString("project_text");

                HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();

                hm.put("project_id",project_id);
                hm.put("project_name",project_name);
                hm.put("project_location",project_location);
                hm.put("project_img",project_img);
                hm.put("project_background",project_background);
                hm.put("project_tagline",project_tagline);
                hm.put("project_text",project_text);

                pro_info_list.add(hm);

                //set texts

                if(!project_tagline.equals("") && !project_text.equals(""))
                {
                    pro_tag_line.setText(project_tagline);

                    pro_text.setText(project_text);
                }
                else if(project_tagline.equals("") && !project_text.equals(""))
                {
                    pro_tag_line.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pro_text.setText(project_text);
                }
                else if(!project_tagline.equals("") && project_text.equals(""))
                {
                    pro_tag_line.setText(project_tagline);
                    pro_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    pro_tag_line.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    pro_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                JSONArray project_menu = dataObj.getJSONArray("project_menu_data");

                for(int i = 0; i < project_menu.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject menuObj = project_menu.getJSONObject(i);

                    String menu_name = menuObj.getString("menu_data_name");
                    String menu_img = menuObj.getString("menu_data_img_url");
                    String menu_id = menuObj.getString("project_menu_id");

                    HashMap<String, String> hm1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    hm1.put("menu_id",menu_id);
                    hm1.put("menu_name",menu_name);
                    hm1.put("menu_img",menu_img);

                    pro_menu_list.add(hm1);

                    // creating buttons for menu options

                   MyButton menulayout = new MyButton(ProjectActivity.this);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lay_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.menu_btn_ht));
                    lay_params.setMargins((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.menu_btn_mg_lft_rt),
                            (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.menu_btn_mg_top_bottom),
                            (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.menu_btn_mg_lft_rt),
                            (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.menu_btn_mg_top_bottom));

                    lay_params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

                    menulayout.setLayoutParams(lay_params);

                    menulayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

                    menulayout.setText(menu_name);

                    if(prefs.getInt("screen_ht",0) == 1776 && prefs.getInt("screen_wd",0) == 1080) // for nexus 5 and sony xperia z
                    {
                       menulayout.setTextSize(14);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        menulayout.setTextSize((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.menu_btn_txt_size));
                    }

                    menulayout.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

                    menulayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_btn_layout1);

                    //menulayout.setTag(menu_id);

                    menulayout.setTag(i);

                    menulayout.setOnClickListener(menuClickListener);

                    project_menu_lay.addView(menulayout);
                }

                if(!project_img.equals(""))
                {
                    new DownloadProjectImage(projectImage).execute(project_img);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code for the Activity. You have only provided one class.

Comment: i think you are use emulator ?

Comment: No, I am using device, even then it is showing the same message,

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the class you are showing at the code, GetProjectInfo, from a main activity like in [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Example:

```
 new GetProjectInfo().execute(string1, string2, string3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have debugger attached when you see this message? If yes, do you also see it without the debugger? If no, then it's most probably a debugger causing your app to slow down.

Particularly, you'll see such messages if you're hanging on a breakpoint in debugger, with even bigger numbers of skipped frames (depending how long do you actually wait on the breakpoint).